# I am developing an Android app which contains fonts from regional languages do i require fonts.ttf file

Tags: android

I am developing an android app where I will be consuming a json which contains Hindi fonts but without using .ttf file.I was able to bring the fonts to the UI in the AVDemulator It works fine but is it correct way or any other procedure is there to bring Hindi fonts.

Comment: This question might have been posted earlier still  I am not able to get into a conclusion since I am new to android.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the android devices distributed in India supports Hindi font by default. But still if you want to have any custom hindi font then you must have to add .ttf font file into your asset folder and set it to textview. Use below function to read font file from asset folder

```
static public Typeface getTypefaceFromAsset(String strName, Context context)
{
    Typeface typeFace = Typeface.DEFAULT;
    try
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, strName);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return typeFace;
}
```

Comment: in my case the json created using a java class has as asked me to save it as UTF-8, when I added the hindi fonts  in string array.Then after  saving the java file as utf-8 in eclipse i am exposing the json and i am able to consume the same also still do i require fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you require the .ttf file for font then add your font.ttf file in assets folder and set font like this

for ex:

```
txtFirstName.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/hindifont.ttf"));
```

Comment: in my case the json created using a java class has as asked me to save it as UTF-8, when I added the hindi fonts in string array.Then after saving the java file as utf-8 in eclipse i am exposing the json and i am able to consume the same also still do i require fonts.